Overwriting or Removing an old version of a Direct Distribution Xcode Source Editor Extension?
I created an Xcode source editor extension for myself and installed it through direct distribution, not through app store. So I can't use the app store to uninstall it.
I installed v1 (by running the app that contained my extension) and it showed up and was working as expected. But I found a bug and so I created a v2 and installed that. When I restarted Xcode, it was behaving according to the new v2 behaviors and everything was good. But when I started up Xcode this morning, it's back to using the v1 behaviors. I've tried reinstalling v2 over and over, but when I trigger it in Xcode it just does the v1 behavior that I fixed in v2.
How can I either fully uninstall the extension so that I can do a fresh install of the new one? Note: Not disable, uninstall. I know that I can go and uncheck the box for that extension in my Settings, but I want to uninstall it, not just disable it.
Or, how can I ensure that the updated version gets installed properly and overwrites the old version?

If you throw away the app that contains the extension, that doesn't do it?

@matt It only stops showing in the Extensions screen in the Settings, but Xcode still shows it in the menus and shows it as active.

And does it actually work if you choose it in the menu?
